# Simple game getting error " Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c

It runs at first but then goes back to an error. This is what the log says

"2014-01-26 17:43:23.264 Higher or Lower[26812:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key enter.'"

```
#import "ViewController.h"

int answer = 0;
int guess = 0;
int turn = 0;



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad; {

       [super viewDidLoad];
       _higher.hidden = YES;
       _lower.hidden = YES;
       answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       [_labelGuess resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)enterButton:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSString *input = _labelGuess.text;
        guess = [input intValue ];
        _labelGuess.text=input;

        if (guess > answer) {
            _lower.hidden = NO;
            _higher.hidden = NO;

    }
    else if (guess < answer) {
            _lower.hidden = YES;
            _higher.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
            NSLog(@"Correct! The answer was %i", answer);
    }

        NSLog(@"The random value is %i", answer);
        scanf("%i", &guess);
}


@end
```

//HEADER FILE!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *labelGuess;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *chooseNumber;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *higher;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lower;

- (IBAction)enterButton:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
```

Comment: Check your connections in Interface Builder, and make sure all your outlets (particularly for the `UITextField`) are as they should be. Also, what is that `scanf()` call doing there?

Comment: I got rid of the scant() The outlets seem fine to me, here is the header file...

Comment: Search on the error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding+compliant+for+the+key

Comment: Whoah.  `answer`, `guess` and `turn` are global variables.  Likely not what you need.  Also, `scanf()` in an iOS app makes no sense.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint and run again. Also, when is the `enterButton` method triggered ?

Comment: Breakpoint before #import "ViewController.h" still gets error. Also, why don't I need global variables and scant has been removed. enterButton is triggered at the end when the button is pressed? Couldn't finish that because I've been working on this error. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)